# JQuery - run function if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, case

If checked: #instructions-bar will activate. 
If not checked: #instructions-bar will not activate.

What's the best way to accomplish this within a case statement.. I know multiple if then statements wouldn't be the best way.  Basically, I want to hide the #instructions-bar within each case.  Not the whole switch.

```
<p><input type="checkbox" id="unique-checkbox-name" name="enable-checkbox"/>Checkbox</p>

 $("select[name=map-tool]").change(function (e) {
    var currVal = $(this).val();
    switch (currVal) {
        case "navigation":
            // instructions bar HIDE
            $('#instructions-bar').slideUp('slow');
            // more code
            break;
        case "distance":
            // instructions bar SHOW
            $('#instructions-bar').slideDown('slow');
           // more code
            break;
        case "area":
            // instructions bar HIDE
            $('#instructions-bar').slideUp('slow');
            // more code
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("select[name=map-tool]").change(function (e) {
    var currVal = $(this).val();
    var isChecked = $("#unique-checkbox-name").is(":checked");
    switch (currVal) {
        case "navigation":
            // instructions bar HIDE
            if (isChecked) $('#instructions-bar').slideUp('slow');
            // more code
            break;
        case "distance":
            // instructions bar SHOW
            if (isChecked) $('#instructions-bar').slideDown('slow');
           // more code
            break;
        case "area":
            // instructions bar HIDE
            if (isChecked) $('#instructions-bar').slideUp('slow');
            // more code
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  Will this allow the case switch to run even if not checked?  Confused.  I only need the if statement on showing instructions-bar, not the rest.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that is what you were asking for.  I've updated my answer accordingly.